# Can't connect to sql server box

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, firewall, telnet

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database that is behind a firewall. The asp.net application which is in the DMZ tries to connect to the database, however I am getting an error (*The webapp works fine from my local machine*):

[image]

When I telnet:

```
open 0.0.0.0 1433
```

it says:

```
Connecting to 0.0.0.0 ...
Connection to host lost
```

Does this mean that the firewall is blocking the incoming request? Or is this something else? (IT support assured me the port is open)

Connection string:

```
data source=0.0.0.0; initial catalog=mydb;user id=xxxx;password=xxxx;persist security info=True;packet size=4096;
```

Comment: Show us a sanitized version of you connection string...

Comment: how about enabling Named Pipes in the SQL Config Manager. Then, try using teh machine/instance name to connect...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new UDL file on your ASP server. Open the UDL file, use the interface to successfully connect to the SQL server and save the file. Open the UDL file in a text editor and copy the connection string into your application.

Answer (score 0):

If your sql server is behind a firewall (and it's a good thing that it is), then your web app should not be connecting to it directly. Rather, it should be going through some sort of service layer. That can be implemented in a variety of ways with different technologies. This service should be located physically on a machine that can access the db, and the web server should not be allowed to directly connect to the db machine (or cluster).

So, with that said, let's address your connection string. Try adding 'integrated security=true'. Here's an example:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStringDb1" connectionString="Data Source=MY_SERVER_NAME_OR_IP;Initial Catalog=MyDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Again, it's important to note that the web app itself should only be calling to this service layer (perhaps WCF, or possibly a COM component), not connecting to the data access layer directly. There are lots of samples on how to design these types of applications. Here's one that hopefully may help. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/SukeshMarla/3-tier-architecture-using-Asp-Net/. Good luck.